# Database optimised for set operations

Tags: database, set, set-intersection, set-operations

I want to know the database or platform that will be most suitable for performing heavy set operations.

Especially INTERSECTION, DIFFERENCE over millions of values in sets.

Comment: I find this question intriguing. I would guess that any decent relational database could work well (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MariaDB, MySQL) if there are proper indexes in place. Can you elaborate? How many tables, how many columns, how massive are they, how often the queries run?